# For Loop in R to read in data

Tags: r

I have the following code and I wanna make a for loop out of it. I only have to change the year numbers on all lines (years 1996-2019). The following is my code:

```
# loading health data
health_data_1996 <- read.csv("1996-Annual.csv")
#delete data which is not needed
health_data_1996 <- health_data_1996[!(health_data_1996$Measure.Name != "Unemployment Rate, Annual" & 
health_data_1996$Measure.Name != "High School Graduation"),]
health_data_1996 <- health_data_1996[,-c(1,2,5,7:11)]
#rename value column
colnames(health_data_1996)[3] <- "1996"
```

Can somebody tell me how I could make a for loop out of this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please provide a (small) reproducible example of the data with the same columns as the real data. Do you have one csv per year? Do you want to combine them into one dataset?

Comment: Sorry I'm relative new to R and Stackoverflow. Yes I have one csv per year and I don't wanna combine the dataset already, I just wanna read them in. There are the following 11 columns: Edition, Report.Type, Measure.Name, State.Name, Rank, Value, Score, Lower.CI, Upper.CI, Source, Source.Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to read the datasets and not combine them I suggest the following. I'm assuming here that all your CSV files have the same name structure.

```r
# create a vector with all the years
years <- 1996:2019

# apply the desired function on every value in years consecutively
all_data <- lapply(years, function(y) {
  df <- read.csv(paste0(y, "-Annual.csv"))
  
  df <- df[df$Measure.Name == "Unemployment Rate, Annual" |
      df$Measure.Name == "High School Graduation", ]
  
  df <- df[, -c(1, 2, 5, 7:11)]
  
  colnames(df)[3] <- y
  
  df
})
```

This will give you a named `list` where every element is the dataset for a given year. So for example if you want the data from 2019 you should be able to retrieve it with `all_data[["2019"]]`.